# 'Implicit downcast from object to int' warning when returning an Array

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have a function in GameMain.js:

```
function getTarget( ... ){
   ...
   return [targetX, targetY, objectBehaviour, moveX, moveY];
}
```

As you can see, I return an array. The variables in the array are declared in the function, as well as their types. Then I want to use the array in another script:

```
var targetInfo = gameMain.getTarget( ... );
target = new Vector2(targetInfo[0], targetInfo[1]);
objectBehaviour = targetInfo[2];
moveX = targetInfo[3];
moveY = targetInfo[4];
```

The variables used here are also previously declared with type.
Everything works perfectly, but the 3 last lines give this warning:
"Implicit downcast from 'Object' to 'int'

I'd like to know why I got this warning, because everything is declared as int and nothing should be Object. Note that the 4th last line with the vector2 doesn't give the warning.

Comment: why a warning is bothering you? probably the `array` you return from the function `getTarget()` is considered as array of Object because you are using it as `var targetInfo` and not type casting its values when assigning it to some `int` variables so it type casts it implicitly which is not an issue i guess.

Comment: It's not a real problem, as you said, but I just find them annoying. And in unityscript, I can't hide specific warnings. Still didn't find a solution to the warnings, so I'll just ignore them.

Comment: well if you want to avoid this warning. just type cast your object into `int` before assigning it. and you can set warning to disabled in console window

Comment: Can you give a short code example? I searched a bit, but didn't find how to typecast object to int... Tried `as int` and `int()` but both give errors

Comment: [This](http://united-coders.com/matthias-reuter/all-about-types-part-3/) may be helpful

Comment: try as int[] for the cast (Square brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i finally found a solution with `as int[]`thanks to Venkats comment.
In fact, I lied about `objectBehaviour` to simplifie the question. It's not an `int`, but an `ObjectBehaviour` (an enum I made).
I made two arrays, casted their types and put them in a jagged array, like this:

```
return [[targetX, targetY, moveX, moveY], [objectBehaviour]];
```

in GameMain.js, and in the other script:

```
var targetInfo = gameMain.getTarget( ... );
var targetInfo1 = targetInfo[0] as int[];
var targetInfo2 = targetInfo[1] as ObjectBehaviour[];
target = new Vector2(targetInfo1[0], targetInfo1[1]);
moveX = targetInfo1[2];
moveY = targetInfo1[3];
objectBehaviour = targetInfo2[0];
```

Ty Umair and Venkat for the info!